# Fancybox Chrome autoplay video issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, html5-video

I'm using Fancybox as a lightbox. I have videos set up in external html docs and are loaded in the Fancybox when the link is clicked from the main doc. The problem is Fancybox is somehow preventing "autoplay" in Chrome. Firefox seems to be working ok.

```
From index.html

Fancybox script:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".video").fancybox({
'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
'hideOnContentClick': true
});
}); //ready
</script>

Body code:
<li><a class="video" href="video/healthcarevideo1.html">Smart Outsourcing (HIPPA 5010, EMR)</a></li>
<li><a class="video" href="video/healthcarevideo2.html">Guaranteed Rejection of Claims (HIPPA 5010)</a></li>

-->From healthcarevideo1.html:
<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>
```

Any ideas on what the issue may be here?
Thanks!

```
EDIT: JFK, below, is correct. Final code:    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".video").fancybox({
'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
'width': 640, //or whatever
'height': 360, //or whatever
'type' : 'iframe',
'scrolling': 'no'
});
}); //ready
</script>
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Could you show the content of your healthcarevideo html files? Have you try setting `'type':'iframe'` in your custom fancybox script? (you may need to set the `width` and `height` too)

Comment: I added the video code above. The Fancybox loads, shows the movie, the movie just doesn't play. Firefox everything works fine. I can drag the video html over to the browser and it plays in Chrome. That's why I thought it may be the Fancybox.

Comment: Does autoplay works in Chrome when you're not using Fancybox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try setting `'type':'iframe'` in your custom fancybox script? (you may need to set the `width` and `height` too) like:

```
$(".video").fancybox({
 'type': 'iframe',
 'width': 660,
 'height': 380,
 'scrolling': 'no',
 'overlayOpacity': 0.9
});
```